# Degree of divisors on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

When Hartshorne talked about divisors on (noetherian, integral, separated, regular in codimension 1) curves (this is on page 137), he defined the degree of $\sum n_iP_i$ (where $P_i$ are closed points) to be $\sum n_i$, but shouldn't degree of a divisor be $\sum n_i \textrm{ deg }P_i$? And when the field is not algebraically closed, the closed points may not have degree 1?

Comment: I presume that in this section, Hartshorne is working over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's a reasonable assumption given Hartshorne.. just want to make sure I'm not missing anything. (I thought Hartshorne usually mentions it when he assumes fields are algebraically closed, but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: He uses a lot of algebraically closed fields. He may have made a standing assumption earlier in the section.

Comment: Degree is also not a good notion if the curve is not proper over a field.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the definition for the degree of a divisor on a projective variety is in page 132. When D is the divisor of a curve then we can say like you, in page 137.